# Variance of Random Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, tensors

If the variance of a random vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a matrix, what is the variance of a random matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ in its standard representation? If we think about $v = \text{vec}(Y) \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$, then I see how we could think about the $\text{var}(v)$ as matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{mn \times mn}$, but is there a more useful tensor structure in working with $Y$ as a matrix?